# API module version

Tags: php, php-extension

When I build a PHP module extension in C, how can I know the "short" version number of PHP I'm dealing with ? (5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.x, ...)

ZEND_MODULE_API_NO only relies on a format like YYYYMMDD (eg: 20060613) !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend Engine defines a few macros in the `php_version.h` header for that purpose:

```
#define PHP_MAJOR_VERSION 5
#define PHP_MINOR_VERSION 3
#define PHP_RELEASE_VERSION 3
#define PHP_EXTRA_VERSION "-1ubuntu9.7"
#define PHP_VERSION "5.3.3-1ubuntu9.7"
#define PHP_VERSION_ID 50303
```

Per example, if you want to check if the extension is running on 5.3, you'd do:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50300) {
    // PHP 5.2 or before!
}
```